# inserting date using c#.Net into SQL Server 2008 using insert query

Tags: c#

I am making desktop application using C#.NET and SQL Server 2008.......in which i took one label name date and had a toolbox datetime picker.and also took field name date in database...........nw i want to insert the date throgh form using datetimepicker and get get inserted  in datatbase.......

using code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SW-PC-20;Integrated security =SSPI;Initial catalog=PSM");

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Campaign(Campaign_id,List_of_thresholds,Duration,Starting_Date,Ending_Date,Total_Budget_of_all_thresholds) values (" + Convert.ToInt32(cbocampaign.Text) + ",'" + cbolist_threshold.Text + "',' " + txtduration.Text + " '," + Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text) + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text) + "," + Convert.ToInt32(txtbudget.Text) + ")", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Insertion successfully done");
```

****PROBLEM :****it is not able to convert datetime picker error occuring .....

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text) `
```

Please give me solution for this and also give me the coding of fetching data into textboxes  using data grid view

regards

shivani

Comment: Will you give us what's this error?

Comment: "Step right up folks!, it's time to play Guess That Error!"

Comment: Oh, if only the DateTimePicker control exposed the selected value as a DateTime, rather than forcing you to fiddle about with the datetime as a text value. Oh. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instad of concuting string, it will solve your problem, and prevent [sql injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in default datetime format. You can try to parse datetime using DateTime.ParseExact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")

Furthermore, I agree with ArsenMkrt, it is better to use parameters.